# Setting up Omniauth Identity to connect with Existing User Model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, omniauth, railscasts

I was going through [this Railscast](http://railscasts.com/episodes/304-omniauth-identity) to setup Omniauth Identity, but I was unclear about one part. He creates a new Model called Identity which then holds the email, name and password fields. However, I already have a user model with those fields, so can I just connect Identity to it? How would I do that?

Answer (score 0):

Since the goal is to separate "identity" from "user", using your User model is not recommended. Create a new `identities` table and migrate each user's email, name, and password in. Now you can remove password from your User model, and use OmniAuth to sign up/sign in.

If you *must* use your User model, you can override in the configuration by specifying `:model => User`